# How can I run Lua code in an Angular Application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lua

I am currently building an Angular 10 application that requires me to be able to run  Lua code when a certain button is clicked.

However, I am not sure how to process the code.

I have looked at the following library [fengari](https://fengari.io/) which uses Javascript but i am not sure how to implement this within an Angular application.

I have tried adding the script to the `index.html` but I'm not sure how to then use it across the application.

I also installed the npm package [fengari npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fengari) but couldn't see anything regarding typescript typing. Maybe i just completely missed it.

If anyone has any experience with running Lua code within Javascript, any help or information would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thank you for your reply! I will take an in-depth look at what you posted. I think I'm a little confused on how to import a js lib within TS

Comment: That's the easy part. Your TS project will be configured to use either CommonJS or ES6 modules.  Use the same method you use with your other TS code.